# Key errors in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting key error whenever I select a column in DataFrame (pandas)
except the first column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/biostats.csv")
df["Weight (lbs)"]
```

Result:

```
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Weight (lbs)'
```

Comment: Can you show what your table looks like? It seems there is no column called `'Weight (lbs)'`, or at least the table is not parsed correctly.

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` then do `df["Weight (lbs)"]`

Comment: Download your `csv` file and use `read_csv` locally. Apparently there's a bug and it is reading the double quotes as part of the strings. You'd have to do `df['"Weight (lbs)"']` to make it work, which is awful.

Comment: I would not recommend @Erfan's solution because that's a workaround that won't solve the problem. The values in yoour data frame will also have double quotes around them, and that's most likely *not* what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the columns in your CSV include a " around the column names.

To fix that:

```
df=pd.read_csv("https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/biostats.csv")
df.columns = [ "Name", "Sex","Age","Height (in)", "Weight (lbs)"]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you run df.columns you will find that your columns are : ['Name', '     "Sex"', ' "Age"', ' "Height (in)"', ' "Weight (lbs)"']

so you have to use:

```
df[' "Weight (lbs)"']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your csv file has column names with qoutes included. You could use:

```
df.columns=[column.replace("\"","") for column in df.columns]
```

In this way you can deal with any file which has similar problem.